# How does someone position their arms on this Reverse Fly machine?

Tags: gym, machine

My gym has just got [this](https://www.technogym.com/int/reverse-fly-selection-pro.html) machine.  Unfortunately, their idea of "easy-to-read" instructions is a stick man without hands, whose arms are obscured by the padding.

Any video I have seen of a reverse fly machine seems more about putting your arms on grips far in front, but nothing here seems to match.

I've seen people look confused at the machine, but no one using it so I don't feel too alone in my confusion!  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sit facing the rest, with your chest on it. Your arms go up and forward 90 degrees, with the upper arm just above the elbow on the pads. Here's a pic at full contraction:

[image]